# check query no result in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I would like to find a way to check if my query result doesn't return a value. Example:
If in my tableExample on database there isn' t the id that I'm passing , the method should return an exception or a simple echo that indicate me the not presence in the table

My code below:

```
try{
     DB::table('tableExample')
        ->where('id', "2")
        ->update(['update' => "1"]);

        return $result= array("result" => "true" );
      }catch(QueryException $e){
        return $result= array("result" => "false" );
        echo " - ".$e;
      }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question I didn't get your problem

Comment: what is `turn`  it should be `return` ? and from where `$id` comes ?

Answer (score 1):

[`update`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_update) method return integer value (`affected rows`) if success, try like this

```
try{
    $update = DB::table('tableExample')
        ->where('id', "2")
        ->update(['update' => "1"]);
    if($update){
        $result = array("result" => true );
    }else{
        $result = array("result" => false,"message"=>"Not Found" );
    }
}catch(QueryException $e){
    $result = array("result" => false,"message"=>$e->getMessage() );
}
return $result;
```

Comment: that else its so redundant there :\

Comment: No its ok, value of `$result` changes accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use `findOrFail()` helper method. That way you do not need to wrap the action in a `try catch` since if  findOrFail does not find the row then it will throw an exception.

```
    $resultData = DB::table('tableExample')->findOrFail(2);

    $update = $resultData->update(['update' => "1"]);

    if(!$update){
      return response(['results'=>false]);
    }

    return response(['results'=> true]); 

}
```

`update()` method returns a boolean true for success on update and versa.

Comment: you removed `try...catch` part, `update()` returns integer value not Boolean : [check this](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_update)

Comment: @btl if for some reason update fails then the feedback its propper so its correctly placed there :)

Comment: Or you could replace it all with one line... `return response(['results'=> !!$update]);`.

Comment: @user2486 yeah I know exactly what `update()` returns and how it will act. So if its returned as integer still the if statment will work correctly :) So your comment its unesccessary!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `whereExists` clause:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-exists-clauses

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_exists

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: Why? Because I didn't include a fully implemented solution?

Comment: Yes @LeoinstanceofKelmendi is right, please answer with code, yes implemented solution.